# Вывод информации из Word

Tags: c#, winforms

День добрый, делаю программу в которой присутствует методичка, загружающая HTML-документ, содержащий в себе текст и формулы, которые являются картинками, загруженными на фотохостинг. Дело в том, что если на компьютере отсутствует интернет, то формулы не выводятся, а лишь альтернативный текст.
Есть мысль выводить всю информацию вместе с формулами из ворда в какой-либо компонент WinForms. Как это можно реализовать, или есть другие альтернативные пути?

Comment: А нельзя изображения загружать не на хостинг, а использовать  Data URL? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

Answer (score -2):

Можно хранить методичку с формулами из Equation в файле rtf и просматривать на форме через `RichTextBox`, загружать так: `richTextBox1.LoadFile("123.rtf");`

Comment: это больше комментарий, чем ответ